# What triggers the option to buy a guild?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

In Medieval 2: Total War I am occasionally prompted with the opportunity to buy one guild or another, such as the `Thieves Guild` or the `Woodsman's Guild`.  What causes these opportunities to appear?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it's the repeated purchase or use of units, buildings, and abilities related to that particular guild - for example, frequently buying and using assassins will lead to the Assassin's Guild offering to open a chapter in one of your cities. Which city is chosen is determined by where you do the missions/recruiting/etc - in the above example, if you buy a lot of assassin's from a single city, that city is probably going to be the one that the Assassin's Guild offers to set up in.

The same goes for the second and third level guilds, with some changes to the rules: you can only have one second-level guild of a type in your empire, and there can only be one third-level guild of a type in the whole world. Also note that you can only have one guild in each city - once you accept a guild in a city no other guild will offer to build there unless you destroy the old guild first. You will also gradually lose guild points, meaning that unless you're actively working on a specific guild it's very unlikely you'll ever achieve a third-level structure.

For detailed information on what actions attract which guilds, as well as all the mechanics for them, follow this link: http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?t=77577